# Internal link in WordPress footer.php file not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a child theme and I have added a link in the footer.php file to a page within my website. I used the WordPress recommended:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'PAGE TITLE' ) ) ); ?>">PAGE TITLE</a>
```

which displays the proper URL when the link is clicked, but I get a 404 error. I determined that if I set my permalink setting to Default it will bring up the page, but the URL is the permalink ID, not the slug. I want to use Post name for my permalinks for SEO purposes. Any suggestions?

Comment: what does the URL look like before and after you change the permalink structure?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. It turns out it was a .htaccess file permissions problem, not a code problem.

Answer (score 1):

With out seeing what the resulting URL is it's hard to say what the problem is.  I'm guessing you're using the example here on the [get_permalink() function page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink).  My guess is that you simply don't need to use the esc_url() function.  According to [Stephen Harris](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/data-sanitization-and-validation-with-wordpress--wp-25536) get_permalink() performs it's own sanitation so using esc_url() on it is not necessary despite it being "recommended" on the codex.

It would be more helpful if you posted a link to your page or at least the resulting code.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. While attempting to try your suggestion, I spotted a message concerning the writability of my .htaccess file. I changed the permissions on the file and then updated the permalinks and it now works. Thanks again for your assistance!